# Computing age from to_timedelta is weird, and DateOffset is not scalable over a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns:

```
          date   age
0   2016-01-05  47.0
1   2016-01-05  43.0
2   2016-01-05  28.0
3   2016-01-05  46.0
4   2016-01-04  39.0
```

What I want is another column with the difference between the date and age:

```
          date   age           dob
0   2016-01-05  47.0    1969-01-05
1   2016-01-05  43.0    1973-01-05
2   2016-01-05  28.0    1988-01-05
3   2016-01-05  46.0    1970-01-05
4   2016-01-04  39.0    1977-01-04
```

Seems simple enough, but the simple `df['date'] - df['age'].astype('timedelta64[Y]')` gives:

```
0   1969-01-04 14:27:36
1   1973-01-04 13:44:24
2   1988-01-05 05:02:24
3   1970-01-04 20:16:48
4   1977-01-03 13:01:12
```

Why the additional time stamp? Even `pd.to_timedelta(df['age'], unit='Y')` gives the same result, with an additional warning that `unit='Y'` is deprecated.

Further, `df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=df['age'])` throws (understandably):

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I can use `apply` in the second option, `df['date'] - df['age'].apply(lambda a: pd.DateOffset(years=a))`, to circuitously get the correct result, and (understandably) `PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to DatetimeArray not vectorized`.

What is a good (pythonic and vectorized) solution here?

Comment: a **year** is not a perfectly well defined unit of time. It's *approximately* 365.24218967 days, which is why you start to get some of these weird fractions. If you have an extremely massive DataFrame and getting the date is perfectly necessary, perhaps try looping through the 100 or so years with `pd.DateOffset` instead of a much worse loop over the rows

Answer (score 2):

If you need to specify a different non-standard offset (i.e. months or years) for every row it can save time to **loop over the unique offsets instead of rows**. Accomplish this with a `groupby`.

This will be especially true when the number of unique offsets is << the number of rows in your DataFrame. This is very likely the case with realistic values for integer ages and a very long DataFrame.

```
pd.concat([gp.assign(dob = gp.date - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=age))
           for age, gp in df.groupby('age', sort=False)])

        date   age        dob
0 2016-01-05  47.0 1969-01-05
1 2016-01-05  43.0 1973-01-05
2 2016-01-05  28.0 1988-01-05
3 2016-01-05  46.0 1970-01-05
4 2016-01-04  39.0 1977-01-04
```

---

Some timings:

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def with_groupby(df):
    s = pd.concat([gp.date - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=idx)
                   for idx, gp in df.groupby('age', sort=False)])
    return s
    
def with_apply(df):
    s = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=int(x['age'])), axis=1)
    return s
    
    
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('1980-01-01', 
                                                                         freq='50D', periods=100), n),
                                  'age': np.random.choice(range(100), n)}), 
    kernels=[lambda df: with_groupby(df),
             lambda df: with_apply(df)],
    labels=["groupby", "apply"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 20)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x.sort_index().compare(y.sort_index()).empty,
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

[image]