# Given a start date and number of months, work out end date P

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to work out the end date and have succeeded but code takes long to run. How can I improve the following code? Also `df['end_date']` is a new variable? i tried:
     `df['end_date'] =  []`, 
 and appending it but getting a length error. I therefore wrote the below Many thanks, d

```
i = 0
j = 0
df['end_date'] = df['start_date']
for i in range(len(df['start_date'])):
    for j in range(len(df['term'])):
        df['end_date'] = (df['start_date'][i].date() +  dt.timedelta(df['term'][j]*365/12))
        i+=1
        j+=1
```

my dataset looks like :

### start_date term

1. 2010-03-01  24
2. 2009-11-01  36
3. 2012-08-01  24

Comment: can you add an example of input data? couple rows would be enough

Comment: If you want to do this *correctly* you will probably need to loop. That is, a month is not a well-defined unit of time and adding calendar months is not vectorized for different offsets. Sure you can add 365/12 days, but that can be sloppy and lead to issues. If you truly want to add a calendar month (such that Feb 12 + 1 month  is March 12, and not like 4 PM on March 14th) then you can loop over the unique month offsets, instead of rows in the DataFrame. It's a much more manageable number of iterations

Comment: I.e. See something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174267/computing-age-from-to-timedelta-is-weird-and-dateoffset-is-not-scalable-over-a. That uses `years` as the offset, but you could easily change it to `months` for calendar month addition

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'end_date' is a datetime, something like this should work:

```
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['term']*365/12, unit='d')
```

However, the proper way of handling month offsets would be to use `pd.DateOffset`:

```
# if the offset was the same for all records, it would be ok to just
# offsets = pd.DateOffset(months=the_offset)
# but here, we need to handle different values
offsets = df['term'].map(lambda term: pd.DateOffset(months=term))
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + offsets
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you should be able to do this:

```py
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'].date() +  dt.timedelta(df['term']*365/12)
```

You are looping over a dataframe, which you should avoid. Try to use the pandas API directly as much as possibly to use its underlying performance optimizations.

Also, you are manually incrementing `i` and `j`, but these are also the indices in your `for` loops and therefore incremented by the loop operator. So it should not be necessary to increment them manually.

Comment: `dt.timedelta` won't work on pd.Series. Use pd.to_timedelta for this

Comment: @Fabian Hertwig thanks, though i get a AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @Marat thanks . do you mean on the start date variable, i get 
TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

Comment: @Jienkles if `start_date` is a string, use `pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']).dt.date` instead. However, it would be a lot better to use `pd.DateOffset` to work with month offsets instead

Comment: @Jienkles if it is a datetime column (seems to be the case), then just `df['start_date'].dt.date`

Comment: @Marat no it was a datetime already thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213264/discussion-between-jienkles-and-marat).

Comment: @ALollz thanks but i get the same as the other errors, which is
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @Marat gives error PerformanceWarning, but works, so im happy thanks a million