# Pandas: How to sum date formatted column (dtype('<M8[ns]')) and year object column (dtype('O'))?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a new column called `my_df['Contract End Date']` that contains the sum of the date contained in `my_df['Contract Start']` and the total years contained in `my_df['Term']`. The problem is that the `my_df['Contract Start']` column is formatted as a date `(dtype('<M8[ns]'))` and the `my_df['Term']` column is formatted as an object `(dtype('O'))`.

What is the shortest way to achieve this?

Heres a sample of my df

```
my_dict = {'Contract Start': {0: Timestamp('2016-01-29 00:00:00'), 1: pd.NaT, 2: pd.NaT, 3: Timestamp('2016-01-15 00:00:00')}, 'Term': {0: '2 years', 1: '2 years', 2: np.nan, 3: '3 years'}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

Comment: Are the terms always in years or can they be months or days?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174267/computing-age-from-to-timedelta-is-weird-and-dateoffset-is-not-scalable-over-a. Just strip the `' years'` from your Term column, convert to numeric, then you can add.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Always in years.

Comment: @StevenGonzález do you need to take into consideration leap year or is it assumed that one year is always 365 days?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I know that it is not perfect, but I'm assuming a 365 days always.

Comment: @StevenGonzález try `my_df['Contract End Date'] = my_df['Contract Start'] + pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_numeric(my_df['Term'].str.replace('years', ''))*365, 'D')`