# How to add a column with number of years to another column with dates with Pandas

Tags: pandas, date

Let me show an example to better explain my problem:

I have a dataframe with a Date column and Number of Years column. I am trying to create the New Date column by adding the number of years to the years of the Date column, as the example below:

| Date | Number_Years | New Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-23 | 5 | 2025-09-23 |
| 2019-11-09 | 7 | 2026-11-09 |
| 2014-08-08 | 3 | 2017-08-08 |

I have tried the following:

```
df1['New Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df1['Number_Years'] , unit='Y')
```

I get an error and the following is not quite what I need, because I just need the four digit year to change on the date:

```
df1['New Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df1['Number_Years']*365 , unit='D')
```

Also tried:

```
df1['New Date'] = df1['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=df1['Number_Years'])
```

and it does not work either.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174267/computing-age-from-to-timedelta-is-weird-and-dateoffset-is-not-scalable-over-a. The `groupby` might seem a little complicated, but it will scale very well for a larger DataFrame with a few unique offsets (likely the case here), because with the calendar year addition you are otherwise forced to do a slow loop over the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `astype`:

```
df['New Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[D]') \
                 + df['Number_Years'].astype('timedelta64[Y]')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date  Number_Years   New Date
0  2020-09-23             5 2025-09-23
1  2019-11-09             7 2026-11-09
2  2014-08-08             3 2017-08-08
```